# Swift - UIPageController disable scrolling with touching pageIndicators

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I want to disable the feature of scrolling with touching the page indicators and scroll to related page faster.

How can I disable pageControl's interaction?

See below gif to understand what I meant:

[image]

Comment: Please try to better explain what you are asking. Your "gif" shows only tapping a page control, it doesn't tell us what you don't like about it, or what you want different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've disabled the pageControl user interaction to solve that gesture.

```
pageControl.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```